# CPQ Managed Package Still Necessary?

Tags: cpq

Is a managed package still needed to get up and running with CPQ? (formerly SteelBrick)

I installed this package in our sandbox:

https://test.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t61000000kgtgAAA

I see a new "Salesforce CPQ" app in the app selector, but it is unclear how to assign a license to a user.  There is a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZBRo8KGy_s&feature=youtu.be) video that shows a "Manage Licenses" link on the "Installed Packages" page and I do not see that link.

I realize that this is a huge product, so I am just trying to make sure I have the basics installed correctly at this point.

This is what the package looks like from the "Installed Packages" section of the app:

[image: Salesforce CPQ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandboxes do not require you to assign licenses. All uses are essentially given a license and there will be no manage license link in the sandbox

Comment: But the managed package installation is still required, correct?

Comment: @dana - as far as I know yes

Answer (score 1):

From what I have observed, in sandbox, salesforce CPQ doesn't give you the link for **Manage licenses**.

Please see below screenshot from my production

[image]

I checked in my sandbox and even I don't have manage license link.

Also while installing, below options are given to you to ensure CPQ/ any managed package is installed for required users

[image]